list cbind with two list element in R
I have 2 lists:
a = list(data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 21:30), data.frame(a = 11:20, b = 31:40))
b = list(data.frame(c = letters[1:10]), data.frame(c = LETTERS[1:10]))

And I want to cbind automatically them so that the column c gets paired with each element in the a list.
This is what I expext (manually)
c = list(data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 21:30, c = letters[1:10]), data.frame(a = 11:20, b = 31:40, c = LETTERS[1:10]))

When trying this,
do.call(cbind, a, b)

I get
Error in if (quote) args <- lapply(args, enquote) : 
  the condition has length > 1

Expected output:
c
[[1]]
    a  b c
1   1 21 a
2   2 22 b
3   3 23 c
4   4 24 d
5   5 25 e
6   6 26 f
7   7 27 g
8   8 28 h
9   9 29 i
10 10 30 j

[[2]]
    a  b c
1  11 31 A
2  12 32 B
3  13 33 C
4  14 34 D
5  15 35 E
6  16 36 F
7  17 37 G
8  18 38 H
9  19 39 I
10 20 40 J


"When trying this, do.call(cbind, a, b)" The third parameter of do.call is quote = FALSE. Read the documentation before trying stuff like that.

Yes, but even this do.call(cbind, c(a,b)) doesn't give the proper output nor do.call(cbind, list(a,b)). I haven't added all failed attempts!

You should work on understanding what do.call does. None of these attempts make sense.

We can use Map()
> Map("cbind", a, b)
[[1]]
    a  b c
1   1 21 a
2   2 22 b
3   3 23 c
4   4 24 d
5   5 25 e
6   6 26 f
7   7 27 g
8   8 28 h
9   9 29 i
10 10 30 j

[[2]]
    a  b c
1  11 31 A
2  12 32 B
3  13 33 C
4  14 34 D
5  15 35 E
6  16 36 F
7  17 37 G
8  18 38 H
9  19 39 I
10 20 40 J

as long as a and b are of same length and their data frames are equal in row numbers.
